# Forwarding by Different Paths Does Not Work

Tags: angular, docker, nginx

I have three Nginx Docker container instances running. The first one is just a proxy and the other two serve as Angular applications.

It works perfectly with the only one location / and I have it already running without any troubles for some months. For certain reasons, I have to add the location /foo to distinguish between two Angular applications (embedded by Nginx). The first is running under :8000 as the second is running under :8100.

The configuration of the proxy with two locations / and /foo as follows:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.org;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        client_max_body_size 9000M;
}

server {

        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name example.ort;
        location ^~ /foo {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_pass http://example.org:8100/;
                proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_pass http://example.org:8000;
                proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        }

        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/example.org.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/example.org.key;
        client_max_body_size 9000M;
}
```

Since it still works without any troubles for /, /foo does not work. / links to :8000 and /foo to :8100. Both have THE SAME Nginx config. The Nginx config of both Angular applications as follows:

```
server {
    listen       80 default_server;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /assets/ {
      root /usr/share/nginx/html;
      autoindex off;
    }

    location /api/ {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
      proxy_pass http://backend:8080/;
      proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
    }

  client_max_body_size 500M;
}
```

I have already tried to rewrite the url by

```
rewrite /foo/(.*) /$1 break;
```

since I guessed the wrong Url is passed. But is doesn't solve the problem.

Just to restrict the error cause, when calling example.org:8000 or example.org:8100, it works without problems. Only /foo causes problems.

**Important observation:** When I call example.org/foo, the html code tells me that the title is correct, but the web browser only shows a blank page (the instance running at :8100 seems to be reachable). But in the JavaScript console, there occurs an error message:

> ncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Does anyone have a good idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does the javascript console say in the Network tab? Is the browser downloading all javascript and stylesheet files correctly?

Comment: That's a good question. First of all, the browser seems to download all files. But in the case of /, the main.25909383923ec4a7ed1a.js really contains JavaScript code (the case / is working and provides a working Angular page). In the case of /foo, there is also a file main.1cc44a9f2a64c7d61217.js, but the content is HTML code that remembers me strongly of the index.html (what seems to be wrong!).

Comment: My guess is that your angular app doesn't know it's been served on a subpath and thus can't find the assets. Try checking the actual logs of your upstream nginx and see what path you're actually requesting.

Comment: If you have an idea of how to check the "upstream nginx", feel free to share your approach ... ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to check your /foo angular app serving nginx logs for the actual calls your browser is making. My guess is that the browser is requiring /foo/<asset path> but your app does not understand that route.

Comment: Now that I think more about it, it's probably the opposite. Let me make a quick test and I'll post an answer with my idea.

Comment: Sorry, can't replicate what I had in mind. Anyway to clarify my guess, I think it's possible that the requests your browser does to download the assets of the /foo angular app, go to the root app and get a 404 obviously. But you can ensure that by checking the log of both nginx upstream nginx.